# What is the system of neighbourhoods for an $x∈G$, where $G$ is a non-empty set with the discrete metric.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the system of neighbourhoods for an $x∈G$, where $G$ is a non-empty set with the discrete metric.

I've tried the question and know that for some $ε> 0$ the open ball $U(x, ε)$ is contained within a subset of $G$. But how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Suppose that $x\in A\subseteq G$. Can you find an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq A$? If so, $A$ is a nbhd of $x$.

Comment: I'm still a little confused :(

Comment: If $x\in G$, what points of $G$ are in $B(x,1)$? Those are the points $y$ such that $d(x,y)<1$; which points are those?

Comment: It'd just be $x$ because $d(x,y)=1$ if $x$ does not equal to $y$. Okay I got it now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes! So if $x\in A\subseteq G$, then $B(x,1)$ is an open ball around $x$ that is contained entirely inside $A$, which by definition means that $A$ is a nbhd of $x$. And $A$ was **any** subset of $G$ containing $x$, so the nbhd of $x$ are all the subsets of $G$ that contain $x$.